# Why doesn't strict aliasing rule apply to int* and unsigned*?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior, strict-aliasing

In the C language, we cannot access an object using an lvalue expression that has an incompatible type with the effective type of that object as this yields to undefined behaviour. And based on this fact, the strict aliasing rule states that two pointers cannot alias each other (refer to the same object in memory) if they have incompatible types. But in **p6.2.4** of C11 standard, it is allowed to access an unsigned effective type with a signed version lvalue and vice-versa.

Because of the last paragraph two pointers `int *a` and `unsigned *b` may alias each other and the change of the value of the object pointed by one of them might lead to the change of the value of the object pointed by the other (Because it is the same object).

Let's demonstrate this on the compiler level:

```
int f (int *a, unsigned *b)
{
    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;

    return *a;
}
```

The generated assembly of the above function looks like this on GCC 6.3.0 with **-O2**:

```
0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:   movl   $0x1,(%rdi)
   6:   movl   $0x2,(%rsi)
   c:   mov    (%rdi),%eax
   e:   retq
```

Which is quite expected because GCC doesn't optimize the return value and still reads the value `*a` again after the write to `*b` (Because the change of `*b` might lead to the change of `*a`).

But with this other function :

```
int ga;
unsigned gb;

int *g (int **a, unsigned **b)
{
    *a = &ga;
    *b = &gb;

    return *a;
}
```

The generated assembly is quite surprising (GCC -O2):

```
0000000000000010 <g>:
  10:   lea    0x0(%rip),%rax        # 17 <g+0x7>
  17:   lea    0x0(%rip),%rdx        # 1e <g+0xe>
  1e:   mov    %rax,(%rdi)
  21:   mov    %rdx,(%rsi)
  24:   retq
```

The return value is optimized and it is not read again after the write to `*b`. I know that `int *a` and `unsigned *b` are not compatible types but what about the rule in paragraph **P6.2.4** (It is allowed to access an unsigned effective type with a signed version lvalue and vice-versa)? Why doesn't it apply in this situation? And why does the compiler make that kind of optimization in this case?

There is somthing I don't understand about this whole story of compatible types and strict aliasing. Can someone enlighten us? (And please explain why do two pointers have incompatible types but can alias each other, think of `int *a` and `unsigned *b`).

Comment: `unsigned *` is not an unsigned type.

Comment: In the first example, `b` and `unsigned` play no part. Simlarly in the second more complex example. Where is the "pointer aliasing"?

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean, `b` plays no part? The assignment to `*b` is the only reason the asm code reloads `*a` for the return value, and that's because of aliasing.

Comment: @melpomene what aliasing?

Comment: @WeatherVane The potential aliasing that the compiler has to take into account when generating code.

Comment: @melpomene what aliasing? `b` and its context is irrelevant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180128/discussion-between-melpomene-and-weather-vane).

Comment: you seem to be assuming the reason *a is loaded in first example has to do with aliasing, but really has to do with the constant. It wasn't already in eax so had to be loaded. 2nd example return value was already in eax.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Example 1 could've been compiled as `movl $1, %eax; movl %eax, (%rdi); movl $2, (%rsi); retq`, saving one memory access if not for aliasing.

Comment: Re: “But in p6.2.4 of C11 standard, it is allowed to access an unsigned effective type with a signed version lvalue and vice-versa”: I think you mean clause 6.5, paragraph 7.

Comment: Please also read the examples in [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228315/1708801) it might help clarify the concepts a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the intended meaning of the signed/unsigned exemption, one must first understand the background of those types.  The C language didn't originally have an "unsigned" integer type, but was instead designed for use on two's-complement machines with quiet wraparound on overflow.  While there were a few operations, most notably the relational operators, divide, remainder, and right-shift, where signed and unsigned behaviors would differ, performing most operations on signed types would yield the same bit patterns as performing those same operations on unsigned types, thus minimizing the need for the latter.

Although unsigned types are certainly useful even on quiet-wraparound two's-complement machines, they are indispensable on platforms that do not support quiet-wraparound two's-complement semantics.  Because C did not initially support such platforms, however, a lot of code which logically "should" have used used unsigned types, and would have used them if they'd existed sooner, was written to use signed types instead.  The authors of the Standard did not want the type-access rules to create any difficulty interfacing between code which used signed types because unsigned types weren't available when it was written, and code which used unsigned types because they were available and their use would make sense.

The historical reasons for treating `int` and `unsigned` interchangeably would apply equally to allowing objects of type `int*` to be accessed using lvalues of type `unsigned*` and vice versa, `int**` to be accessed using `unsigned**`, etc.  While the Standard doesn't explicitly specify that any such usages should be allowed, it also neglects to mention some other uses that should obviously be allowed, and thus cannot be reasonably viewed as fully and completely describing everything that implementations should support.

The Standard fails to distinguish between two kinds of circumstances involving pointer-based type punning--those which involve aliasing, and those which don't-- beyond a non-normative footnote saying that the purpose of the rules is to indicate when things may alias.  The distinction is illustrated below:

```
int *x;
unsigned thing;
int *usesAliasingUnlessXandPDisjoint(unsigned **p)
{
  if (x)
    *p = &thing;
  return x;
}
```

if `x` and `*p` identify the same storage there would be aliasing between `*p` and `x`, because the creation of `p` and the write via `*p` would be separated by a conflicting access to the storage using the lvalue `x`.  However, given something like:

```
unsigned thing;
unsigned writeUnsignedPtr(unsigned **p)
{ *p = &thing; }

int *x;
int *doesNotUseAliasing(void)
{
  if (x)
    writeUnsignedPtr((unsigned**)&x);
  return x;
}
```

there would be no aliasing between the `*p` argument and `x`, since within the lifetime of the passed pointer `p`, neither `x` nor any other other pointer or lvalue not derived from `p`, is used to access the same storage as `*p`.  I think it's clear the authors of the Standard wanted to allow for the latter pattern.  I think it's less clear whether they wanted to allow the former even for lvalues of type `signed` and `unsigned` [as opposed to `signed*` or `unsigned*`], or didn't realize that limiting application of the rule to cases that actually involve aliasing would be sufficient to allow the latter.

The way gcc and clang interpret the aliasing rules does not extend the compatibility between `int` and `unsigned` to `int*` and `unsigned*`--a limitation which is allowable given the wording of the Standard, but which--at least in cases not involving aliasing, I would regard as contrary to the Standard's stated purpose.

Your particular example does involve aliasing in cases where `*a` and `*b` overlap, since either `a` was created first and a conflicting access via `*b` happens between such creation and the last use of `*a`, or `b` was created first and a conflicting access via `*a` happens between such creation and the last use of `b`.  I'm not sure whether the authors of the Standard intended to allow such usage or not, but the same reasons that would justify allowing `int` and `unsigned` would apply equally to `int*` and `unsigned*`.  On the other hand, gcc and clang's behavior does not seem to be dictated by what the authors of the Standard meant to say as indicated by the published Rationale, but rather by what they fail to demand that compilers do.

Answer (score 4):

Given `int **a` and `unsigned **b`, the type of `*a` is not the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of `*b`, nor is `*b` the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of `*a`. Therefore, this rule permitting aliasing via corresponding signed or unsigned types does not apply. As no other rules permitting aliasing apply either, the compiler is entitled to assume the write to `*b` does not modify `*a`, and therefore the value the compiler wrote to `*a` in `*a = &ga;` is still present in `*a` for the `return *a;` statement.

The fact that `int *` points to a signed `int` does not make it a signed type. It is a pointer. `int *` and `unsigned *` are pointers to different types. Even if they were considered signed or unsigned, they would be signed or unsigned pointers to different types: If `int *` were a signed pointer, it would be a signed pointer to `int`, and the corresponding unsigned version would be an unsigned pointer to `int`, not any pointer to `unsigned`.

Comment: The Standard could certainly be interpreted that way.  Given the history of signed and unsigned types, and the fact that implementations are allowed (and in some cases expected) to define behaviors in cases beyond those mandated by the Standard when doing so would make sense, I don't think the authors intended compilers to interpret the permissions as narrowly as gcc and clang do.